# How to use Test::Simple conditionally?

Tags: perl, testing

I would like to add the option to test my Program conditionally with a command line option like `--test` which execute `&test`.

Unfortunately even if I add `use Test::Simple tests => 1` inside the `&test` subroutine, Perl think I want to do the tests everywhere else.

Is it possible to use `Test::Simple` or even `Test::More` only when needed?

Comment: What are you using for command line processing? Something from the `Getopt::` namespace, some CLI generator or a homebrew solution?

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I am using `GetOpt::Long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the whole `Test::More` statement only loaded under certain conditions you can do the following:

```
if( $condition ) {
  require Test::More ;
  import Test::More ;
  plan tests => 1 ;

  # Place your tests here...
}
```

This will result in the same as `use Test::More tests => 1;`.

Your problem results in the fact that `use` is a compile time statement that will be executed wether inside a `if` statement (evaluated at runtime) or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `use if`. It looks a bit ugly, because you'll have to ensure that the variables, upon which `if` (the pragma) operates must be set a "compile-time" (that is in `BEGIN`-block order).

```
my $test;
BEGIN{
  GetOptions( "test" => \$test) or die "wrong arguments"
}

myTest() if $test;

say "normal program";

sub myTest{
  use if $test => 'Test::Simple', tests => 1;
  ok("1", "tests are running");
}
```

Comment: Nice trick. This is a very good example for the use of  `BEGIN`